# Command prompt in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, console, pyqt5

I am making server, but then someone close console with [X] it is very dangerous.  I can't find way to disable [X] in console, so there is way to put console in PyQt5?

Example of console code:

```
while True:
     a = input('Enter command: ')
     if a == 'stop':  # Exit command
          exit()
     elif: a == 'abc'  # Others commadns in console
          pass
```

Comment: 1) the questions must be specific and that involves the technologies also so you cannot ask for answers for n technologies that fulfill the same function so if you also want a solution for tkinter then create a new post, 2) what do you have What to see PyQt5 with the code you provide? Your question is unclear. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Perhaps you should consider running it without a window to be closed, perhaps as a scheduled task or a service. Without specific information, your question is far to broad to be answered. But generally, if you have a windowed application running, even if you have managed to hide or remove its built-in close mechnism, an end user can still close it. If the program does not need a window, then an end user is less likely to seek out methods of closing it, because there's no GUI showing them that it's running. If the process runs under a different user privileges, then the end user can't close it.